# Use of @event in C# razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a reserved variables in my model called @event

How do I use that in Razor? @@event just escapes the @, and \@ doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@(@event)` should work - enclosing the variable/expression in parentheses.

I also believe in the proper context you can simply ignore the `@` and use `@event` and Razor will understand.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work...
Here's an example from my code:

@Model.(@event)

Comment: You'll have to use `@(Model.@event)`, enclosing the entire expression.